# do queue ownership based sharing rules evaluate queue members?

Tags: sharing-rule, queue

i'm simplifying sharing on an object by changing ownership to queues and adding sharing rules to groups to grant read access as required.

i ran into some doubts this morning bc of the language on the sharing page, where it says "criteria = owner IN Queue: XYZ"

[image: sharing settings page]

sample scenario:

- record A is owned by Queue Q1
- record B is owned by Queue Q2
- owner based sharing rule to grant read access from records where "owner is in queue Q1" to group G1
- owner based sharing rule to grant read access from records where "owner is in queue Q2" to group G2
- user Bob is in queue Q1 and Q2

because Bob is "IN" Q2, would record A be shared to group G2?

my understanding and testing indicates no.  this means that for queues, the rule is set based on owner == queue, not that the owner is "IN" the queue, though the language on the page made me think otherwise.

i'm doing more testing but also wanted validation that i'm thinking this through fully.

Comment: have done more testing, including recalculating sharing rules, and quite sure that IN doesnt actually mean IN when it comes to records *owned by queues*.   have not tested yet with records owned by users in the queue.